# How do I create an OnClick Event for a table cell's inner html

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make the text WITHIN a table cell trigger an onclick function using JavaScript.  I am able to make the cell itself trigger the onClick event but that is not what I want.

```
var table = document.getElementById(tableName);
var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

cell1.innerHTML = "some text"
//how do I make the text within the innerHTML trigger an onclick event?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual text within a table cell cannot be bound to an event listener as such. If the text within the table cell is in another tag ( such as a paragraph, span, div or whatever ) then you can use a slight trick to test for which element triggered the event by comparing the event `target` and the event `currentTarget` properties.

You can click anywhere in the cell and nothing will happen unless you click on the paragraph - at which point the `target` will no longer be the same as the `currentTarget` that was registered with the event listener. There is, as far as I am aware, no way of doing this with just the raw text within the table cell - and ultimately why would you need to do so anyway?

```
<table id='banana' border=1 cellpadding='5px' cellspacing='2px'>
    <!-- content to follow -->
</table>


<script>

    const nl=String.fromCharCode(10);

    var id='banana';

    var table = document.getElementById( id );
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
        cell.innerHTML = 'This is some basic text';

    var p=document.createElement('p');
        p.innerText='This is a Paragraph within the table cell';

        cell.appendChild( p )


    cell.addEventListener( 'click', function(e){
        if( e.target != e.currentTarget ) alert( [ 'target: '+e.target, 'currentTarget: '+e.currentTarget, 'text: '+e.target.innerText ].join( nl ) )
    });
</script>
```

Following on from the comment made previously about triggering an event when a user selects text within the table cell, you can possibly try the following:

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup',(e)=>{
    alert( 'Text has been selected? '+ window.getSelection() )
});
```

There is, as I just discovered, a `selectionchange` event that might be of interest - [more information from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectionchange_event)

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener to `cell1`.

```
cell1.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(this.innerText);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use onclick for onClick event

```
cell1.onclick = function () 
{
   console.log("onclick");
};
```

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

cell1.innerHTML = "some text"

cell1.onclick = function () 
{
   console.log("onclick");
};
```

```html
<table id="table">
 </table>
```

Comment: I would not like it the onClick event to be called when the Cell is selected. I would like it to be called when the text itself is selected.